# Question regarding finding inverse of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The most common method to find the inverse of a invertible square matrix is to apply row operations to the matrix and reduce it to the identity matrix.

An row operation is applied to the matrix by doing a left multiplication by an elementary matrix.

Denote the elementary matrices as $E_1, E_2, ... , E_n$ , then

$(E_1, E_2, ... , E_n)A = I$ , where $E_1, E_2, ... , E_n$ is the inverse of $A$.

However, the procedure to check whether two matrices $A$ , $B$ are the inverse of each other is to check that $AB=I$ and $BA=I$.

Why do we claim that $(E_1, E_2, ... , E_n)$ is the inverse of $A$ without checking that $A(E_1, E_2, ... , E_n) = I$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because for square matrices existence of any one side inverse imply the existence of the other. For proof check this out [If $AB = I$ then $BA = I$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/if-ab-i-then-ba-i?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Thank you. Merry christmas!